# How is this MySQL query vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

In a comment on a previous question, someone said that the following sql statement opens me up to sql injection:

```
select
    ss.*,
    se.name as engine,
    ss.last_run_at + interval ss.refresh_frequency day as next_run_at,
    se.logo_name    
from 
    searches ss join search_engines se on ss.engine_id = se.id
where
    ss.user_id='.$user_id.'
group by ss.id
order by ss.project_id, ss.domain, ss.keywords
```

Assuming that the `$userid` variable is properly escaped, how does this make me vulnerable, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You should consider using binding parameters. You seem fine, but you can't be sure that the next developer working on it won't add another variable earlier on in the query, where it's more vulnerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it is properly escaped, it doesn't make you vulnerable. The thing is that escaping properly is harder than it looks at first sight, and you condemn yourself to escape properly every time you do a query like that. If possible, avoid all that trouble and use prepared statements (or binded parameters or parameterized queries). The idea is to allow the data access library to escape values properly.

For example, in PHP, using [mysqli](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm):

```
$db_connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT thing FROM stuff WHERE id = ?");
$statement->bind_param("i", $user_id); //$user_id is an integer which goes 
                                       //in place of ?
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 15):

Every SQL interface library worth using has some kind of support for binding parameters.  Don't try to be clever, just use it.

You may really, really think/hope you've escaped stuff properly, but it's just not worth the time you don't.

Also, several databases support prepared statement caching, so doing it right can also bring you efficiency gains.

Easier, safer, faster.

Comment: +1 Because binding is the "real and professional" answer to this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2):

If **$user_id** is escaped, then you should not be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

In this case, I would also ensure that the $user_id is numeric or an integer (depending on the exact type required). **You should always limit the data to the most restrictive type you can.**

Comment: If he were sure $user_id is numeric, he wouldn't need the single-quotes around the interpolated value in his SQL.

Comment: I read that as using single rather than double quoted strings, hence the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If it is properly escaped and validated, then you don't have a problem.

The problem arises when it is not properly escaped or validated. This could occur by sloppy coding or an oversight.

The problem is not with particular instances, but with the pattern. This pattern makes SQL injection possible, while the other pattern makes it impossible.

Answer (score 1):

All answers are good and right, but I feel I need to add that the `prepare`/`execute` paradigm is not the *only* solution, either. You *should* have a database abstraction layer, rather than using the library functions directly and such a layer is a good place to explicitly escape string parameters, whether you let `prepare` do it, or you do it yourself.

Comment: Database abstraction layers are overrated. And in any case it's the prepare/execute paradigm what matters, whether it's done by a DAL or directly in a database specific layer.

Comment: I could riposte by opining that prepare/execute is over-hyped. :-) A good DAL is like any other abstraction layer: just thick enough to be useful, but not so thin it's merely renaming functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'Properly Escaped' here is the keyword. In your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316142/mysql-multi-table-join), I'm making the assumption that your code is copy pasted from your production code, and since you asked question about three tables join, I also make the assumption that you didn't do proper escaping, hence my remark on SQL Injection attack.

To answer your question, as so many people here has described, **IF** the variable has been  'Properly Escaped', then you have no problem. But why trouble yourself by doing that? As some people have pointed out, sometimes Properly Escaping is not a straightforward thing to do. There are patterns and library in PHP that makes SQL Injection impossible, why don't we just use that? (I also deliberately make assumption that your code is in fact PHP). Vinko Vrsalovic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316367/how-is-this-mysql-query-vulnerable-to-sql-injection#316372) may give you ideas on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That statement as such isn't really a problem, its "safe", however I don't know how you are doing this (one level up on the API stack). If $user_id is getting inserted into the statement using string operations (like as if you are letting Php automatically fill out the statement) then its dangerous.

If its getting filled in using a binding API, then your ready to go.