# Set a Value from a SQL table select statement to a local variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

I'm trying to take the CustomerID from the SQL select statement and then assign it to a $_SESSION variable i can use later on during the session.

MY CODE:

```
session_start();  
    $Username = $request->getParam('Username');
    $PassW = $request->getParam('PassW');


    $sql = "SELECT CustomerID FROM login WHERE Username= '$Username' AND PassW='$PassW' LIMIT 1";


    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($result) == 1){  
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
        $_SESSION['CustomerID'] = '****CUSTOMER ID FROM TABLE****';
```

I'm new to this so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set variable from SELECT PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930961/set-variable-from-select-php)

Comment: what is the actual question?

Answer (score -1):

Sovled it.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

needed to be

```
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```